# Is it possible to provide custom content for the VS2012 Start Page?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012 (and 2010, too) has a Start Page that has links and streamed videos. Is it possible for my package to provide content on this page, e.g., create a separate section next to Welcome/Windows 8/etc.?

Answer (score 6):

I finally got a custom start page working in VS2012 - my issue was I could not install the Start Page Project Template in 2012 as the extension only installs on 2010 (which I don't have access to) and my My Documents folder is mapped to a network drive, so putting the raw XAML file in My Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Startpages didn't work as Visual Studio refused to use this "untrustworthy file".

1. Download the Start Page Template from [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f655a5dc-1a2d-4eca-b774-76c352c03b87/).
2. Rename the file to .zip and extract it.
3. Copy the "\Solution\CSharp\Extensibility\StartPage.zip" file to your project template folder (by default "My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#").
4. Create a new project using this template.
5. Follow the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj991932.aspx) to upgrade from 2010 to 2012 start page.

   - Update the project properties target framework to 4.5.
   - Update the project references in the Control project by removing the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0 reference and adding the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0 and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.11.0 references.
   - Update the namespaces references in the xaml file by replacing the existing ones with the two below.

   > ```
   > xmlns:vs="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0"
   > xmlns:vsfxim="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.11.0"
   > ```

   - Replace the references to `vsfx:VsBrushes` keys to `vs:EnvironmentColors` keys, e.g. `vsfx:VsBrushes.StartPageBackgroundKey` to `vs:EnvironmentColors.StartPageTabBackgroundBrushKey`
6. In the VSIX project, make the following changes to the `source.extension.vsixmanifest` file (values depending on if 2010 support is desired, it is not for me):

   - Add an author, the default empty tag is not allowed: `<Author>Ken</Author>`
   - Change/add the visual studio support version to 11.0: `<VisualStudio Version="11.0">`
   - Change the supported runtime edition to include 4.5: `<SupportedFrameworkRuntimeEdition MinVersion="4.5" MaxVersion="4.5" />`
7. The VSIX solution should now build and spit out a VSIX file in the project bin folder. Install this and you can now choose your Start Page from the drop down list in the visual studio options.

I haven't actually developed my custom start page beyond this, but hopefully it is a helpful to people wanting to get started developing them with VS2012

EDIT: A project which includes a basic 2012 start page, custom control and can be deployed via VSIX: [template](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3424077/StartPageTemplate.zip)

Comment: Ken, can you maybe post somewhere a full example?

Comment: @Clueless, I have added a link to my post to a sample project - let me know if that works/is useful!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the template ,you should upload it to Visual Studio Gallery!

Answer (score 2):

Custom Start Pages, via google:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa991992.aspx

Comment: It's really helpful to take some of the link's content and post it, even just the title, in case the link goes down.